# Python 3.11, pipenv éditable package

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv, python-3.11

I have my python 3.11 project here: **E:/DEV/CUSTOMER/MYPROJECT**
I have created  virtualenv inside my project with **PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT** so my virtual env is in **E:/DEV/CUSTOMER/MYPROJECT/.venv**

I have another package in **E:/DEV/CUSTOMER/MYPACKAGE**

I tried to install my package in editable mode into my virtualenv.

A new file is created into virtualenv : *E:/DEV/CUSTOMER/MYPROJECT/.venv/Lib/site-packages/__editable ___.mypackage.pth* and contains the path to E:/DEV/CUSTOMER/MYPACKAGE

But when i launch my project, it doesn't find MYPACKAGE, whereas normally the .pth files are added to the python path

The behavior is the same whether I run in debug via vscode or run via .bat

```
%VENV_PYEXE% main.py
```

if I manually add the path contained in the .pth file into the pythonpath in the .bat, then it works

```
set PYTHONPATH=E:/DEV/CUSTOMER/MYPACKAGE;%PYTHONPATH%
%VENV_PYEXE% main.py
```

Comment: How do you launch? [edit] the question.